# How to profile fusepy operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, fuse

I am writing a FUSE file system using the fusepy ctypes library (https://github.com/terencehonles/fusepy) for Python.  Is there a way to profile the fuse operations?  When I try to run the instantiation of FUSE with cProfile, I get unusable output:

```
         924 function calls (911 primitive calls) in 5.575 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.575    5.575 <string>:1(<module>)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1209(debug)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1221(info)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1452(getEffectiveLevel)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:1466(isEnabledFor)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:239(load)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:267(loads)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:363(__getattr__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:370(__getitem__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:372(maketree)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.573    5.573 __init__.py:384(mount)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:388(_maketree)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 __init__.py:42(normalize_encoding)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abc.py:377(get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1184(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1200(__init__)
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1252(register)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1256(_registry_get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1281(add_argument)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1328(add_argument_group)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1338(_add_action)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1402(_get_positional_kwargs)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1454(_pop_action_class)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1458(_get_handler)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1467(_check_conflict)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1507(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:151(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1529(_add_action)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 argparse.py:1577(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1613(identity)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1684(_add_action)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1696(_get_positional_actions)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1697(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1704(parse_args)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1711(parse_known_args)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1749(_parse_known_args)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1796(take_action)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1894(consume_positionals)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:194(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:1955(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2032(_match_arguments_partial)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2038(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2042(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2048(_parse_optional)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2150(_get_nargs_pattern)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2194(_get_values)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2246(_get_value)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2272(_check_value)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:2312(_get_formatter)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:554(_metavar_formatter)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:563(format)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:570(_format_args)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:784(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:826(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 argparse.py:855(__call__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:238(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:287(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 codecs.py:297(decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.574    5.574 commands.py:159(mount)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 decoder.py:347(decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 decoder.py:358(raw_decode)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:148(__init__)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:152(__hash__)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:155(_make_key)
       18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:167(<genexpr>)
    12/10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 functools.py:241(wrapper)
        1    5.573    5.573    5.573    5.573 fuse.py:334(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fuse.py:357(<listcomp>)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fuse.py:377(_normalize_fuse_options)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fuse.py:385(_wrapper)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fuse.py:603(destroy)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fuse.py:699(destroy)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 fuse.py:823(__call__)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 genericpath.py:15(exists)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 gettext.py:111(_expand_lang)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 gettext.py:353(find)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 gettext.py:393(translation)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 gettext.py:459(dgettext)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 gettext.py:497(gettext)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 locale.py:339(normalize)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 locale.py:574(getpreferredencoding)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 mount.py:34(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    5.573    5.573 mount.py:419(mount)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 os.py:668(__getitem__)
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 os.py:734(encode)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 os.py:738(decode)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 path.py:16(rootdir)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 path.py:22(fuserootdir)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 path.py:40(treefile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 path.py:46(ctreefile)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:38(_get_sep)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 posixpath.py:71(join)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:153(match)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:212(compile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 re.py:264(_compile)
      4/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:32(_compile)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:357(_simple)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:364(_compile_info)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:470(isstring)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:473(_code)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_compile.py:488(compile)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:127(__len__)
       17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:131(__getitem__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:135(__setitem__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:139(append)
      6/3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:141(getwidth)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:179(__init__)
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:184(__next)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:203(match)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:209(get)
      2/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:340(_parse_sub)
      2/1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:418(_parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:68(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:702(fix_flags)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:714(parse)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:73(opengroup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:84(closegroup)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sre_parse.py:91(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:125(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:131(__iter__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:145(files)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:57(__init__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:70(__iter__)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:76(__setitem__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 tree.py:95(__init__)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method callable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method compile}
        1    0.000    0.000    5.575    5.575 {built-in method exec}
       69    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method getattr}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method getgid}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method getuid}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method hasattr}
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method hash}
       51    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method isinstance}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method iter}
    50/47    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method listdir}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method min}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method nl_langinfo}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method open}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method ord}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method pointer}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method repr}
       31    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method setattr}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method signal}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method sizeof}
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method stat}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method time}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method utf_8_decode}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
       74    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'decode' of 'bytes' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       14    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'encode' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'end' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
       27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'endswith' of 'str' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'extend' of 'list' objects}
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'find' of 'str' objects}
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'groups' of '_sre.SRE_Match' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'isalnum' of 'str' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'items' of 'dict' objects}
        5    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lstrip' of 'str' objects}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'dict' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'list' objects}
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'replace' of 'str' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reverse' of 'list' objects}
       41    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects}
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
       29    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
```

cProfile only profiles fuse.py as a whole, instead of counting the FUSE operations separately.  Is there a way to profile the FUSE operations as well?